# Suppose $f(x)$ has second derivative. And $f(1)=f(2)=5$, $\min\limits_{x\in[1,2]}f(x)=2$.

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f(x)$ has second derivative. And $f(1)=f(2)=5$, $\min\limits_{x\in[1,2]}f(x)=2$. Prove $$\min\limits_{x\in[1,2]}f''(x)\ge24$$
I know this is about Taylor expasion, mostly should expand $f(x)$ at the point makes $f(x)=2$ which is also a local minimum. But what confused me is it need a relation make the minimum greater than a special number. All I met before is minimum less that sth. How should I deal with this kind of problem.

Comment: It is not true as stated. Take $f(x)=5+3\sin(2\pi(x-1))$. It satisfies the assumptions, but [has a point with *negative* $f''(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+5%2B3sin(2*pi*(x-1))+for+x%3D1..2).

Comment: @A.Γ. Thanks for the counter example. I missed conditions for $f'$ beyond that there is a root in $[1,2]$.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simpler than what you imagine: in order to minimize the (locally positive) second derivative, the minimum of $f$ must be attained in the middle of the interval $x \in (1,2)$, so $\bar x=\frac 3 2$. At this point, a crude value of $f''(\bar x)$ is given by
$$
[(5-2)/(1/2)-(2-5)(1/2)]/(1/2)=2((3*2)+(3*2))=24,
$$
which is a "centered finite-difference formula", holding for instance for the 2nd order polynomial interpolating your 3 values.

Edit: I misunderstood the problem: i thought the question was to show that, at the point $\bar x$ where $f(\bar x)=2$, then $f''(\bar x) \geq 24$.

Comment: Why does the minimum has to be in the middle?

Comment: Imagine a (smooth enough) symmetric function that decreases first from $5$ to $2$, then stays constant $2$ then increases back to $5$. Then $f''(1/2)=0$.